# e(fx)clipse runnable jar export - javafx.application.Application class not found

Tags: java-8, executable-jar, efxclipse

I'm coding a JavaFX app using eclipse Oxygen and e(fx)clipse plugin running on debian 9 (stretch).

I've exported it as a runnable jar.

When launching an error is raised:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue :

in eclipse my java compiler was java-se 8  but I was using open-jdk 8 in my own desktop environment. Changing my java environment using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

to java-se 8 solved the problem.